# Convert epoch time to decimal year in Javascript or Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, datetime

*Example:*
GMT Wednesday, January 20, 2016 12:00:01 AM = 1453248001 =>
**2016.0533**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this, accurate to the day:

```rb
Time.at(1453248001).then { |t| t.year + t.yday / 365.25 }
```

and a bit more cumbersome to be precise to the second:

```rb
Time.at(1453248001).then do |t|
  beginning_of_year = Time.utc("#{t.year}-01-01")
  seconds_in_year = Time.utc("#{t.year + 1}-01-01") - beg_of_year
  num_seconds = t - beginning_of_year
  t.year + num_seconds / seconds_in_year
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given time values in seconds, the decimal part of the year is given by:

```
(supplied_time - year_start_time) / seconds_in_year
```

E.g.

```js
// Return decimal UTC year given a time value in seconds
// e.g. 1453248001 (2016-01-20T00:00:01Z) = 2016.0519125999292
function decimalYear(tv) {
  let d = new Date(tv * 1e3);
  let y = d.getUTCFullYear();
  let start = Date.UTC(y, 0, 1);   // Start of UTC year
  let end = Date.UTC(y + 1, 0, 1); // Start of following UTC year
  return y + (d - start) / (end - start);
}

// Time values in seconds
[Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)/1e3|0, // 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z
 Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)/1e3|0, // 2016-01-01T00:00:01Z
 Date.UTC(2016, 0,20, 0, 0, 1)/1e3|0, // 2016-01-20T00:00:01Z
 Date.UTC(2016,11,31,23,59,59)/1e3|0, // 2016-12-31T23:59:59Z
 Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)/1e3|0  // 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z
].forEach(tv => console.log(tv + ' => ' + decimalYear(tv)));
```

Using a general formula gives accurate results regardless of whether the time value is in a leap year or not.

The example in the OP is incorrect:

> Example: GMT Wednesday, January 20, 2016 12:00:01 AM = 1453248001 => 2016.0533

All the following are seconds UTC:

- Time value for 2016-01-12T00:00:01Z is 1453248001
- Start of 2016 is 1451606400
- End of 2016 (i.e. start of 2017) is 1483228800
- (timeValue - startOfYear) ÷ (endOfYear - startOfYear) = 0.0519125999292